# How to get just the newest row from a group where the date is expressed as a string

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database using sqlite3 and one of the columns is storing a date (rfc3339 format) as TEXT.

My database is storing daily values for various objects. In the example below, A and B.

| id | obj | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | A | 2022-05-22T20:02:20.465515Z | 413 |
| 223 | A | 2022-05-23T09:23:39.591774Z | 517 |
| 25 | B | 2022-05-22T20:02:20.469512Z | 963 |
| 948 | B | 2022-05-23T09:23:39.600809Z | 1124 |

What I want to do is to select just the newest date for each object. The objects are referenced in another database. The desired result would be:

| id | obj | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 223 | A | 2022-05-23T09:23:39.591774Z | 517 |
| 948 | B | 2022-05-23T09:23:39.600809Z | 1124 |

If I have hundreds of entries for the obj A, B, C... how can I select just the newest one for each object? (that is, grouped by the value on the column obj)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function such as

```
SELECT id, obj, date, value
  FROM ( SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
               (PARTITION BY obj 
                    ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', date) DESC) AS rn 
           FROM t ) AS tt 
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With simple aggregation:

```
SELECT id, obj, MAX(date) AS date, value
FROM tablename
GROUP BY obj;
```

SQLite returns for each `obj` the row with the most recent `date`.
For reference: [Bare columns in an aggregate query](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query)

Comment: Thank you. I thought sqlite didn't recognize dates, treating it just like text. I will try it out, thanks!

Comment: @MarcosViníciusPetri SQLite does not recognize dates. You store dates as TEXT and this is fine as long as the format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS. `MAX(date)` returns correctly the last date of each group by doing alphanumeric comparison.